# How to write regular expression for an array of integers?

Tags: json, regex, ready-api

I have a JSON Path expression - $.[*].incentiveId which will return me an array of integers in the below format

[11791275, 11792924, 11792242, 11793924]

How do I write a regular expression for the above array of integers?

**Note:** The above array of integers size will vary everytime.

I have written the partial regular expression. ^[[0-9]*,\s and could anyone please help me in completing this regular expression?

Comment: What would you like the regular expression to match? The entire array of integers including brackets and commas or just the integers?

Comment: Entire array including numbers [] comma and spaces in between

Comment: What language or tool? You may try `^\[\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*\]$`. Demo https://regex101.com/r/CzRyPs/1

Comment: Working fine. Thank you so much. Am using Ready API tool and JSON Regex Match Assertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Ready API uses Java for Regular Expressions then you are fine with below regex:

```
^\[\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*\]$
```

It matches `^` beginning of string, then a literal `[` followed by any number of digits. An optional repeating group exists to match comma separated values then a literal `]` and `$` end of input string.

Comment: For my json array with digits it was `\[\d+(?:,\"\d+\")\]`